# Why are Final Cut Pro X and QuickTime Player suddenly refusing to recognize the Targa (.tga) format?

Tags: quicktime, final-cut-pro

I've recently been experimenting with video production on macOS (11.4), and have been using Targa files as frames to import into Final Cut Pro X (10.5.3). After a recent restart, I found that Final Cut Pro refused to recognize these files in its timeline:

[image]

But it's not isolated to FCPX; QuickTime Player itself failed to read them properly, either:

[image]

The files themselves haven't changed, they are and always have been valid Targa files:

```
% file 0001.tga
0001.tga: Targa image data - RGB - RLE 1920 x 1080 x 24
```

Finder can preview them just fine. But it seems like some low-level inability of the OS to properly decode these files. Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: Didn't FCPX just get updated?

Comment: Version 10.5.3, which I am using, was released last week. I have been using it all week without problems, and I see no evidence online that other people have had this or similar problems since that release. These things lead me to conclude the release is unrelated.